# React: private route not navigating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a private route to navigate to a route after the user has logged in. However, I am facing an issue. I don't know why but my router is not transitioning to the desired route. Here's my code:

> Routes.js

```
...
...
<PrivateRoute
  authenticated={localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated")}
  path="/dashboard"
  component={DashBoard}
  exact
></PrivateRoute>
```

> PrivateRoute.js

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, authenticated, ...rest }) => (  
<Route
  {...rest}
  render={props =>
    authenticated ? (
      <Component {...rest} {...props} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: '/',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }}
      />
    )
  }
/>
);

export default PrivateRoute;
```

> Login.js

```
localStorage.setItem("isAuthenticated", true);
this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you set the value of `isAuthenticated`?

Comment: @BenM, I have updated the question. I am assigning it just before calling the history.push

Comment: "I don't know why but my router is not transitioning to the desired route" which route it is redirecting?

Comment: @Asgar, it's not transitioning to the '/dashboard' rather redirecting to the '/'. Somehow, private route is not re reading the data of the localStorage on login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the solution.

```
authenticated={localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated")}
```

the above was invoking the method at application bootstrap due to which I was having the value of null being stored in my authenticated variable so, I changed it to arrow function and passed the argument without invoking it like below:

```
authenticated={() => localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try it?

PrivateRoute.js

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, authenticated, ...rest }) => {
  console.log("authenticated",authenticated)//is it true or false?
  if (authenticated=="true")
    return (
      <Route {...rest}>
        {" "}
        <Component {...rest} {...props} />
      </Route>
    );
  else
    return (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: "/",
          state: { from: props.location },
        }}
      />
    );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Comment: I am getting null in authenticated.

Comment: So thats why it is redirecting to / .you just need to explore why isAuthenticated localStorage variable is null.code that you are showing us is not enough to understand why it is null

Comment: I already know what the issue is. I was asking that somehow value is not being changed.